# How to prevent template base from being called?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a header which looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_MEAN_AND_LEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdint>

class DebugOutput {
public:
    DebugOutput& operator<<(const char* input);
    DebugOutput& operator<<(char* input);

    template <typename T>
    DebugOutput& operator<<(T input) { }

    template<>
    DebugOutput& operator<<<char>(char input) {
        char buffer[] { input, '\0' };
        OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
        return *this;
    }

    DebugOutput& operator<<(int32_t input);
};

namespace debuglogger {
    static DebugOutput out;

    static const char* endl = "\n";
    static const char* error = "ERROR: ";
}
```

It's just a stream which allows me to print to the debug console of Visual Studio in an std::cout sort of way. I've added the templates as a means of preventing ambiguity between operator<<(char input) and operator<<(int32_t input), which prevents my program from compiling.

While this does work, I would very much like for the template base not to be usable. I can't make it private because the specialization is public and C++ doesn't like that. I'd rather avoid throwing an exception inside the template base because I'd like the code to be portable to a project where I might have exceptions turned off. Does using an ASSERT macro work even if the program is running outside of debug mode?

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

I've come to the conclusion that there isn't really a good way of doing what I want. In this case, the only practical way is just to implement all the cases that you need. I thought there would be a simpler way, but implementing everything isn't that bad either.

Comment: Your macro looks wrong, it's spelled `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Comment: I don't get it. Let's say you prevent the primary template from compiling, but how is that different from having separate non-template overloads for `char` and `int32_t`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat When using the operator, I get compiler errors because the compiler doesn't know which overload of the operator to call since char and int32_t are both integer types and they can implicitly convert into each other.

Comment: What about `template<typename T> DebugOutput& operator<<(T) = delete;` ?

Comment: In case of an overloaded operator an exact match should trump all other overloads, so assuming you do pass an `char` or `int32_t` parameter, there shouldn't be an ambiguity. If you're passing something else, you may want to create a template that uses `std::enable_if` to only work for integral types with size > `sizeof(char)` and make sure the version of the operator taking `int32_t` is called.

Comment: *"I get compiler errors because the compiler doesn't know which overload"* Yeah, and you'll get the same error with your current approach, once you delete the primary template as Evg suggested.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The problem with doing that is that any type that isn't accounted for in the header will start referencing a deleted function. Preferably, I would want types that can implicitly convert to int32_t to do so.

Comment: How about adding the overload for `char` instead of the templates? https://godbolt.org/z/7YqT7M9oM. Or just a template for all the cases: https://godbolt.org/z/6dKchc1Kx. I guess it all depends if you need different implementations for each type.

Comment: @fabian The latter case is what is happening. I basically want a way for (for example) unsigned int to automatically use int32_t overload instead of char overload, instead of causing a compilation error. I tried using templates to do so but now unsigned int will prefer to use the base, even if deleted. Is my only option here to implement every case, or is there something I can do? I don't know if I like the enable_if with the size.

Comment: If you want one overload for char and another overload for all integral types that are not char, then make these two *separate* things . Do not specialise function templates.

Comment: *"I've added the templates as a means of preventing [issue X].
While this does work, I would very much like [issue Y]"* -- You might want to read [a certain Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and see how well it matches your situation.